# How draw coordinate points automatically by Python in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I am extracting the coordinates of the vertex lines, but I could not have created them, I tried with itself code:

```py
# create a memory layer with two points
layer =  QgsVectorLayer('Point', 'points' , "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()
# add the first point
pt = QgsFeature()
for i in list_glob:
point1 = QgsPoint(i[0],i[1])
pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point1))
pr.addFeatures([pt])
# update extent of the layer
layer.updateExtents()
# update extent
layer.updateExtents()
# add the layer to the canvas
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

but it does not work

[image]

Comment: add layer.commitChanges() before call updateExtends

Answer (score 1):

Just loop over the list of coordinates

here it is

```
# create a memory layer with two points
layer =  QgsVectorLayer('Point', 'points' , "memory")
pr = layer.dataProvider()
# add the first point
pt = QgsFeature()
for i in list_glob:
    point1 = QgsPoint(i[0],i[1])
    pt.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point1))
    pr.addFeatures([pt])
    layer.commitChanges() 
    # update fields of the layer
    layer.updateFields()
    # update extent
    layer.updateExtents()
# add the layer to the canvas
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```